# Calculate the area of the right triangle using polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

My solution was: $$\int_0^{π/3} \int_1^{\secθ} rdrdθ$$
However the correct solution is: $$\int_0^{π/3} \int_0^{\secθ} rdrdθ$$

I don't see the radius anywhere being zero, so I do not understand why the lower limit of the inner integral is zero. We also know that at $x = 1 \iff r\cosθ = 1 \underset{θ =0}{\iff} r = 1$

My question are:

1. Why is my integral wrong?
2. What would the area given by my integral look like?

Comment: The shaded triangle contains the origin.

Comment: $0$ would be the origin thus the radius $r$ 'starts' at the origin and 'ends' at $\sec(\theta)$ Your integral would have $r$ start at $1$ and up at $\sec\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine the region contains the origin $r$ should start from $0$. Your claim

> $x = 1 \iff r\cosθ = 1 \underset{θ =0}{\iff} r = 1$

is not correct. Because $r \cos \theta =1$ represents only the line $x=1$. When you substitute $\theta = 0$ you are reffering to the point $(1,0)$ in cartisean coordinates.

Your integral represents the area of the given region when you intersect with  it the unit circle.

Comment: Now I understand it.